# Has May Golan or her new ministry engaged in significant feminist initiatives?

Tags: israel, feminism

AFAICT from Wikipedia, May Golan is most famous for opposing illegal immigration to Israel. But she was appointed to lead the new Ministry for the Advancement of Women's Status (established May 1st). Has she [before appointment] or her new ministry engaged in significant feminist projects?

Comment: And I mean apart from criticizing other feminists https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4BeaHrCzz-E

Comment: I think she is basically working against the claimed goal, or at least following the coalition discipline. Not, that I remember a single initiative of her. Calcalist has a post in Hebrew that tries to collect in one place her support for the anti-agenda at https://newmedia.calcalist.co.il/magazine-20-07-23/m01.html